# Set focus to one thing when clicking on another?

Tags: javascript

This is probably very simple to do in Javascript, but I don't know how to.

Example:

```
<input type="textbox" id="txt">
<input type="button" id="btn">
```

Say I want to click on btn and have it set focus on txt, how would I go about doing that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
OnClick="document.getElementById('txt').focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript & HTML code:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var text = document.getElementById('txt');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    text.focus();
});
```

```html
<input type="textbox" id="txt">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click me">
```

This is the only thing you have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `element.focus()` method.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var txt = document.getElementById('txt');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    txt.focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing the same thing with jQuery. Cleaner and easier.

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#txt").focus();
});
```

`event.preventDefault();` will stop the form button from submitting to wherever it would normally go. Might not be necessary?

Downside of doing it this way is that you must include jQuery.